# Extracting data from a text file - repeated values

Tags: java, regex, extract

> 79 0009!017009!0479%0009!0479 0009!0469%0009!0469
>   0009!0459%0009!0459'009 0009!0459%0009!0449 0009!0449%0009!0449
>   0009!0439%0009!0439 0009!0429%0009!0429'009 0009!0429%0009!0419
>   0009!0419%0009!0409 000'009!0399 0009!0389%0009!0389'009
>   0009!0379%0009!0369 0009!0349%0009!0349 0009!0339%0009!0339
>   0009!0339%0009!0329'009 0009!0329%0009!0329 0009!032

In this data, I'm supposed to extract the number 47, 46 , 45 , 44 and so on. I´m supposed to avoid the rest. The numbers always follow this flow - 9!0 no 9%
for example: 9!0 42 9% 
Which language should I go about to solve this and which function might help me? 
Is there any function that can position a special character and copy the next two or three elements?
Ex: 9!0 42 9% and ' 009 
look out for ! and then copy 42 from there and look out for ' that refers to another value (009). It's like two different regex to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever language you want, or even a unix command line utility like `sed`, `awk`, or `grep`. The regex should be something like this - you want to match 9!0 followed by digits followed by 0%. Use this regex: `9!0(\d+)0%` (or if the numbers are all two digits, `9!0(\d{2})0%`).

Answer (score 0):

This is perl:

```
@result = $subject =~ m/(?<=9!0)\d+(?=9%)/g;
```

It will give you an array of all your numbers. You didn't provide a language so I don't know if this is suitable for you or not.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=9!0)\\d+(?=9%)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
    // match start: regexMatcher.start()
    // match end: regexMatcher.end()
}
```

Comment: Java is very much preferrable

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, my regex solution is simply "9!.(\d\d)"

And here's a full solution in powershell, which can be easily correlated to other .net langs

```
$t="79 0009!017009!0479%0009!0479 0009!0469%0009!0469 0009!0459%0009!0459'009 0009!0459%0009!0449 0009!0449%0009!0449 0009!0439%0009!0439 0009!0429%0009!0429'009 0009!0429%0009!0419 0009!0419%0009!0409 000'009!0399 0009!0389%0009!0389'009 0009!0379%0009!0369 0009!0349%0009!0349 0009!0339%0009!0339 0009!0339%0009!0329'009 0009!0329%0009!0329 0009!032"
$p="9!.(\d\d)"
$ms=[regex]::match($t,$p)
while ($ms.Success) {write-host $ms.groups[1].value;$ms=$ms.NextMatch()}
```